# Heroku Postgresql DB - Unable to update database once deployed

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, heroku

I am using Heroku to deploy my postgresql database project. The site I created using PHP, HTML5 and CSS works fine on localhost with phpmyadmin and the equivalent MySQL database. But, when I transferred it over to Heroku only the SELECT queries work (inserts, updates, and deletes are no good).

The only changes from my localhost to heroku site lie in my .env and file to create the php data object which I pasted below. Can anyone tell me where to look next to solve this issue? Heroku error logs don't show any error. I'm using pgAdmin4 for the postgres db.

**.env file**

`DATABASE_URL="pgsql://postgres:mypassword@localhost:5432/dbname"`

**other file**

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$dbopts = parse_url(getenv('DATABASE_URL'));

$dbopts["path"] = ltrim($dbopts["path"], "/");

$db = new PDO("pgsql:" . sprintf(
"host=%s;port=%s;user=%s;password=%s;dbname=%s",
$dbopts["host"],
$dbopts["port"],
$dbopts["user"],
$dbopts["pass"],
ltrim($dbopts["path"], "/")
));
```

Comment: I wonder if it would be worth having another variable to store the result of the `sprintf()`, so you can easily echo it. Would you show us what is in it, minus any security-sensitive info? (Don't assume what's in it - check what it actually resolves to in PHP).

Comment: Hmm, are you reading the URL from config, parsing it, and then putting it all back together again? Can you just feed `getenv('DATABASE_URL')` into the connection string directly?

Comment: It looks like you're doing `ltrim($dbopts["path"], "/")` twice too - is that deliberate?

Comment: It's usually a very good idea to use the same database software in all environments. Would you be open to (a) switching to Postgres locally or (b) switching to MySQL on Heroku? (That may or may not solve your problem. But even if it doesn't solve the problem it would be nice to rule out.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!! @Chris was correct in that the issue was with the database language migration. Turns out Postgres normalizes attribute names by making them all lowercase, so my php functions (ie array_column) didn't recognize the table attributes with uppercase letters. Noob mistake.

Comment: @halfer the second ltrim was redundant but did not make a difference. I still appreciate the advice as it helped me condense my php data object creation code. Thanks!

Comment: That's great if you fixed it! If you think it might help someone else, please post a summary of the solution below, in an answer proper (or ask @Chris to, so they are appropriately credited).

Comment: I can post an answer if you want, but I just pointed at a possible issue. You brought this across the finish line yourself, @Alicia. Self-answering [is encouraged here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). There's even a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) for it if you get enough upvotes on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to problem:

phpmyadmin only supports MySQL, while I used the free Postgres add-on for Heroku. Migration from phpmyadmin locally to Heroku revealed slight differences in syntax between the two languages.

My particular error had to do with uppercase letters in MySQL attributes being reverted to all lowercase in Postgres. Example in one of my functions:

MySQL Version:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Doctors";
$query = $db->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(); 
$results = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$did = array_column($results, 'ID');
$docid = implode(",", $did);
```

Postgres Version:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Doctors";
$query = $db->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(); 
$results = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$did = array_column($results, 'id');   // difference
$docid = implode(",", $did);
```

If not for a uni project, I would use phpPgAdmin instead of phpmyadmin to avoid migration discrepancies. Thanks @Chris and @halfer!

Comment: Slight clarification: Heroku uses PostgreSQL by default, but there are compatible MySQL providers as well. If you have a good reason for running MySQL on Heroku you can. See https://elements.heroku.com/addons

Comment: @Chris True! PostgreSQL is just the only RDBMS that can be used without giving out your credit card info (unfortunately).